# PUT request from redux actions not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, redux

I am trying to update my MongoDB database containing data for a project information form through a PUT request on my action, but I am unable to get the handleSumbit function on my component to call my project action. I am receiving a 404 error. I have no clue what I am missing or have done wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

My Component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../styles/ViewProject.css'

import { updateProjects } from '../actions/project.actions'


const EditProject = ({ project, match }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [projectName, setProjectName] = useState('')
  const [projectType, setProjectType] = useState('')
  const [multiple, setMultiple] = useState(false)
  const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState(Date)
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  updateProjects(name, email, projectName, projectType, dueDate, url, description)
  console.log('Data ', name, email, projectName)
}

    return(
        <form className="viewProjectContainer" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            {project.map((task, i) => ( 
            <div key={i++} >
                {match.params.id === task._id ? 
                <div className="vp">
                    <div className="vpLeft">
                        <div className="vpTitle">
                            <input className='vpProjectName' defaultValue={task.projectName} onChange={e => setProjectName(e.target.value)} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="vpSub">
                            <p>Submitted by: </p>
                            <label>Name: </label>
                            <input className='vpName' defaultValue={task.name} onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}/>
                            <label>Email: </label>
                            <input className='vpEmail' defaultValue={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="vpDescription">
                            <label>{task.multiple === true ? "(Multiple)" : "Single"}</label>
                            <p>Project Type: </p>
                            <select className='formInput' onChange={e => setProjectType(e.target.value)} defaultValue={projectType}>
                              <optgroup label='Digital'>
                                <option value='banner'>Banner</option>
                                <option value='emailBlast'>Email Blast</option>
                                <option value='productImage'>Product Image</option>
                                <option value='socialMediaAd'>Social Media Ad</option>
                                <option value='video'>Video</option>
                                <option value='websiteMockup'>Website Mockup</option>
                                <option value='other'>Other  (Please be specific in Description)</option>
                              </optgroup>
                              <optgroup label='Physical Product'>
                                <option value='bottleOpener'>Bottle Opener</option>
                                <option value='clothing'>Clothing</option>
                                <option value='keyChain'>Key Chain</option>
                                <option value='popSocket'>Pop Socket</option>
                                <option value='usb'>USB</option>
                                <option value='other'>Other  (Please be specific in Description)</option>
                              </optgroup>
                              <optgroup label='Print'>
                                <option value='businessCard'>Business Card</option>
                                <option value='brochureBiFold'>Brochure - Bi-fold</option>
                                <option value='brochureTriSquare'>Brochure - Trifold Square</option>
                                <option value='brochureTriStandard'>Brochure - Trifold Standard</option>
                                <option value='catalogMore'>Catalog - Less than 50 pages</option>
                                <option value='catalogLess'>Catalog - More than 50 pages</option>
                                <option value='documentFull'>Document - Full Sheet</option>
                                <option value='documentHalf'>Document - Half Sheet</option>
                                <option value='flyer4x6'>Flyer - 4x6</option>
                                <option value='flyer5x7'>Flyer - 5x7</option>
                                <option value='flyer6x9'>Flyer - 6x9</option>
                                <option value='postCard4x6'>Post Card 4x6</option>
                                <option value='postCard5x7'>Post Card 5x7</option>
                                <option value='postCard6x9'>Post Card 6x9</option>
                                <option value='poster11x17'>Poster 11x17</option>
                                <option value='poster24x36'>Poster 24x36</option>
                                <option value='other'>Other  (Please be specific in Description)</option>
                              </optgroup>
                              <optgroup label='Other'>
                                <option value='consultation'>Consultation</option>
                                <option value='labeling'>Labeling</option>
                                <option value='other'>Other  (Please be specific in Description)</option>
                              </optgroup>
                            </select>
                            <div className="vpDescBox">
                              <textarea className='updateDescription' defaultValue={description} onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}></textarea>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="vpRight">
                        <div className="vpTicket">
                            <p>Ticket Number: {task.ticketNumber}</p>
                            <label>Submitted: {task.date} </label>
                            <label>Preferred due date: </label>
                            <input type='date' defaultValue={task.dueDate} onChange={e => setDueDate(e.target.value)}/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>Reference links: </label>
                            <input type='text' defaultValue={task.url} onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)}/>
                            <label></label>

                        </div>
                        <div>
                          <p>Project Status:</p>
                          <p>Task Recieved: {task.recieved === true ? "Recieved" : "Not Revieved"}</p>
                          <p>Task in progress: {task.inProgress === true ? "In Progress" : "Not in Progress"}</p>
                          <p>Completed: {task.completed === true ? "Complete" : "Incomplete"}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>: null}
            </div>

            ))}
            <div className='buttonsContainer'>
            <button type='submit' className='projectViewButton1'><Link to={'/' + match.params.id}>Save</Link></button>


            </div>
        </form>
    )

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    project: state.projects.project,
    id: state.projects.id
  })

  export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { updateProjects }  
  )(EditProject)
```

My action:

```
export function updateProjects(name, email, projectName, projectType, dueDate, url, description) {
    console.log('reducer ', name)
    axios.put('api/projects/update/:id', {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        projectName: projectName,
        projectType: projectType,
        // multiple: multiple,
        dueDate: dueDate,
        url: url,
        description: description
    }).then(resp => {
        console.log("Data updated: ", resp.data)
    })
}
```

My Backend:

```
// @route   PUT api/projects/update/:id
// @desc    Update projects
// @access  Private
router.put('/update/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      name,
      email,
      projectName,
      projectType,
      multiple,
      dueDate,
      reference,
      attachment,
      description,
      ticketNumber,
      received,
      inProgress,
      completed
    } = req.body

    const project = await Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      name,
      email,
      projectName,
      projectType,
      multiple,
      dueDate,
      reference,
      attachment,
      description,
      ticketNumber,
      received,
      inProgress,
      completed
    })

   res.json(project);


  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message)
    res.status(500).send('Server Error')
  }
})
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: is it becasue in action you have the url as  `api/projects/update/:id` while on the api its just `/update/:id`

Comment: please check the url `api/projects/update/:id` . it creates target url relative to your current page url

Comment: @albert I think the backend has a scoped router.

Comment: Does the same api works in postman? 
If yes, check your route and pass id as it should be some value.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you are hitting with the `axios.put` is `api/projects/update/:id`, which is incomplete. You should put your host as well. For example: `http://localhost:8000/api/projects/update/:id`

And also, you need to specify a proper value for `:id` in the URL. Not sure if you left that out in purpose for example's sake but just wanna point that one out too haha.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
xhr.js:166 PUT http://localhost:3000/update/api/projects/update/5dc205905cc9f7320596b294 404 (Not Found)

 - for some reason the route is automatically adding the first "update" in the route...Why is that??

Comment: is your backend-server running on `localhost:3000`? @Dopendeasy

Comment: @hussain.codes it's set to 8000 on my backend `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8000`

Comment: okay, i think your front-end is hitting on localhost:3000 instead of localhost:8000, can you please confirm that by checking network tab in devtools. if this is the case then you need to setup proxy for your backend in your front-end package.json @Dopendeasy .

Comment: There is a proxy in my front-end package.json. My other POST/GET requests work. I am not being able to get the PUT request to. Is it something with my code? What else can I do? @hussain.codes

Comment: as @Edrian said, you need to pass a actual id in your put request, in your action instead of `/api/projects/update/:id`, you need to use something like `/api/projects/update/1`.

Answer (score 0):

in your react project folder's package.json file :

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:8000"
```

your http url should be below :

```
axios.put('/api/projects/update/', {
  params: {
    id: 'value of id'
  }
});
```

or :

```
 axios.put(`/api/projects/update/${value of id}`)
```